# autohotkey caps lock to ctrl not releasing

Tags: autohotkey, remap, ctrl, capslock

I'm using AutoHotkey to map the `Caps Lock` to `Ctrl`, and trying to use the `Ctrl + K` as `Tab` in Total Commander.

```
SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff
Capslock::Ctrl

#ifWinActive ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
  ^k::Send, {Tab}
#ifWinActive
```

When i using the `Ctrl + K` remap with the normal `Ctrl`, it works fine. But when i trying to use it with the `Caps Lock + K`, then it works for the first time, but while i'm not releasing the `Caps Lock`, it sends `k` instead of `Tab`. The log says:

```
008: SetCapslockState,AlwaysOff
009: Return (3.49)
; Hiting Ctrl + K twice.
081: Send,{Tab} (0.02)
081: Return (0.30)
081: Send,{Tab} (0.02)
081: Return (1.59)
; Hiting Caps Lock + K twice.
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
009: Return (0.47)
081: Send,{Tab} (0.01)
081: Return (0.73)
; The second Tab is missing, a simple K sent.
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl Up}
009: Return (3.06)
```

Here is the log, when i pressing `Caps Lock + K`, releasing it, then pressing againg:

```
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
009: Return (0.34)
081: Send,{Tab} (0.01)
081: Return (0.08)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl Up}
009: Return (0.34)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
009: Return (0.19)
081: Send,{Tab} (0.01)
081: Return (0.06)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl Up}
009: Return (3.00)
```

I think the source of the problem may be in the `CapsLock::Ctrl`, but i didn't find any solution for it. Somebody meet with this problem?

**EDIT:**

Another interesting thing is when i sending code instead of a simple key, it works without releasing the caps lock:

```
^e::PostMessage, 1075, 3005, , , ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD ; cm_SwitchToNextTab=3005;Switch to next Tab (as Ctrl+Tab) (see TOTALCMD.INC file)
```

The log says:

```
008: SetCapslockState,AlwaysOff
009: Return (8.88)
; Ctrl + E twice.
058: PostMessage,1075,3005,,,ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
058: Return (0.36)
058: PostMessage,1075,3005,,,ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
058: Return (1.76)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
; Caps Lock + E twice.
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
009: Return (0.34)
058: PostMessage,1075,3005,,,ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
058: Return (0.39)
058: PostMessage,1075,3005,,,ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
058: Return (0.28)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl Up}
009: Return (1.47)

; Caps Lock + E twice with releasing.
008: SetCapslockState,AlwaysOff
009: Return (2.54)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
009: Return (0.34)
058: PostMessage,1075,3005,,,ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
058: Return (0.09)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl Up}
009: Return (0.25)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
009: Return (0.23)
058: PostMessage,1075,3005,,,ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD
058: Return (0.08)
009: SetKeyDelay,-1
009: Send,{Blind}{Ctrl Up}
009: Return (1.98)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember running into odd issues like this when I was doing CapsLock remaps as well. Instead of mapping CapsLock to control and then using that combination in your hotkey, you could set CapsLock to do nothing but check the key's state in the `#If` directive. I would think this would resolve most of those odd issues.

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
CapsLock::Return

#If WinActive("ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD") and GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
    k::Send, {Tab}
```

Comment: It works fine - i just made a bit modification to get the CapsLock::Ctrl work outside of Tcmd.
https://gist.github.com/BimbaLaszlo/99bd39b429964e990070

Answer (score 0):

I personally would just check if your window is active on ^k keypress and go from there. I used Untitled - Notepad so I could test.

```
CapsLock::Ctrl
^k::
{
    IfWinActive, Untitled - Notepad
        SendInput, {tab}
    else
        Msgbox
    return
}
```

Comment: It differs from my script in just the order of the lines and the detection of the window. The problem is with "Untitled - Notepad" that it will change when you saving the file with an other name.

Comment: Of course it will change. I merely used it as an example. The OP would obviously have to change it to fit his needs. -- I'm also not using a directive - you are.